# Assembly 8086 program : Character Counting

Tags: assembly, variable-assignment, x86-16

I need help writing a program that should count the number of times a letter appears (either uppercase or lowercase) in a string. You may hard code the string or read it from the console. Your program should display a final count for each letter of the alphabet.

**Example**

Input:

> “Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it. ‐Donald Knuth”

Output:

> A:4,B:3,C:3,D:5,E:9,F:1,G:1,H:3,I:5,J:0,K:1,L:2,M:0,N:5,O:8,P:1,Q:0,R:5,S:1,T:7,U:2,V:3,W:1,X:0,Y:1,Z:0

I think I know the structure but since I don't have 26 registers to work with, I would have to store the value for each incremented letter in its own segment of memory. How do I approach that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you can block out a chunk of memory, and assign some number of bytes for each number. Then to get to a particular letter, use the integer value of the letter times the length of the cell.

For instance, if you picked four bytes (a typical integer length) for each cell, you'd set aside 4*256 bytes, and address into it with something like $STARTOFARRAY+(4*97), and increment that integer.

Comment: then reiterate and try to use less memory :)

Comment: but no premature optimization. :)

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a block of memory large enough to hold 26 elements (each element can be 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes, or as many as you like). A simple way is to create this block of memory in the `.bss` section using [`db`/`dw`/`dd`](http://www.emu8086.com/assembler_tutorial/asm_tutorial_03.html). Each element in this block will correspond to a letter of the alphabet.

Now that you have your block of memory, you need some way of indexing into it. Here you have two alternatives:

- If a character is in the range `['A', 'Z']`, subtract `'A'` to get the index, if the character is in the range `['a', 'z']`, subtract `'a'` to get the index, otherwise ignore the character.
- Convert uppercase to lowercase, or vice versa. If you look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll see that lowercase letters have a greater value than uppercase letters. From there you should be able to work out how to convert a character to lowercase. Once you have your lowercase character, subtract `'a'` from it to get the index.

Once you have your index, use it index into your block of memory by adding the index multiplied by the size of each element to the address of the start of the block. Once you have the address of this element, `inc`rement it.

Repeat until all the characters have been read and then print the result. If you have to write the print function yourself, take note that it becomes slightly less trivial to output numbers with more than one digit. It's no longer a matter of adding `'0'` to get the ASCII equivalent of that number in order to print it.

Comment: How would I allocate a block of memory using db /dw / dd?

Comment: @LucaDeCaprio: A *basic* way is just: `array db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`. There are short-hand ways depending on your assembler.

Comment: Okay so then how would I increment letter B in the array? I've never used db before

Comment: @LucaDeCaprio: The label `array` now refers to the address of a block of 26 bytes. `letter - 'A'` will give you an offset into `array` - add this offset to `array` to get the address of the part of the array referring to the letter. Increment the value at this address.